# How to use string.erase() with a pointer?

Tags: c++, string

The code is simplified from a more complex program but the issue I'm facing still occurs in this more simplified situation.

So I'm trying to erase a character from a string by using a pointer:

```
string str = "Hellxo World";
char *eraseHere;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str[i] == 'x') {
        eraseHere = &str[i];
        str.erase(*eraseHere);
    }
}
```

I expected str to become Hello World, but instead it gives an out_of_range exception and stops the program.

Isn't eraseHere a pointer to the character "x"? I used eraseHere in a printf to try test what's wrong:

```
printf("%c\n",*eraseHere);
```

But it could print that character perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This `std::string::erase` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) could be helpful. You pass either an iterator, or an *index*. And `'x'` is not really a valid index unless you have a string longer than `120` characters (assuming [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `string` class doesn't support erasing with a pointer, so you can't do that.

You can erase with an *iterator* which is nearly the same thing

```
for (auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ) {
    if (*i == 'x')
        i = str.erase(i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Also, even if it worked, your code has the common newbie mistake that you are ignoring that your string gets shorter when you erase a character. So it's not right to do `i++` after erasing a character because you'll skip over the character after the `'x'` you've just removed.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response. What should I do if I want to "store" the position to erase the character with? Because I only want to erase the character until another condition is satisfied (such as until a "#" appears in the string).

Comment: You can store an iterator in a variable and use it later. `string::iterator iter = ...`. Of you could store the offset and create the iterator later `int off = ...; ` then `str.erase(str.begin() + off);` By adding `off` to `str.begin()` you get the iterator that corresponds to the offset.

Comment: Actually if you have the offset you can just use it directly `str.erase(off, 1);` erases one character starting at `off`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply store the index of the 'x', then delete it after you finish the loop... or you can use the *iterator* in the answer above

```
string str = "Hellxo World";
char *eraseHere;
int indx=-1;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
    if (str[i] == 'x') 
    {
        eraseHere = &str[i];
        indx=i;
    }
}
indx!=-1 ? (str.erase(indx,1)):str;
cout<<str<<endl;
```